# Does Azure RBAC roles for AKS work as described in documentation?

Tags: azure-aks, roles, rbac

I am trying to implement Azure RBAC on an existing AKS cluster. I am using Azure AD authentication with Azure RBAC. I understand as per documentation that I do not need create any role/rol bindings in kubernetes, if I use built-in roles. Does this work as expected? If I add built in Azure AKS roles to AAD groups, it will work? It should limit access both in portal and via kubectl.

I tried adding AKS RBAC reader role to group called "Developers". Then I added my user to the same group. I am able to change,view, delete roles/rolebindings via kubectl. This should not be possible as per document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/manage-azure-rbac. Do I need to create roles in k8, and role bindings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work properly as you've described.

Are you absolutely sure you don't have wider Aks Rbac at a higher scope (eg. AKS RBAC Cluster admin at the subscription scope)?

Have you inadvertently used a kubernetes local admin account to authenticate with (az aks get-credentials --admin).

> You will need to reauthenticate with the cluster after changing RBAC roles.

Comment: Can it have something to do with existing kubeconfig file. It works when testing with new users. But for existing users, if I change RBAC roles(or add them to different AD groups with different RBAC roles), the effect does not reflect in kubectl. It reflects in portal though.

Comment: Are they reauthenticating after you change their RBAC role?

Comment: I don't know, this does not look like it works. Or takes a long time to sync. If I change AAD group membership, the RBAC roles do not sync. The user with RBAC reader gets to create/delete the deployments. The reader role was assigned on prod namespace, writer on dev namespace. The user is allowed create/delete deployments in prod namespace. After I change group membership in portal, I do these:
az aks get-credentials --resource-group xxxx --name xxxxx --overwrite-existing.
 kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx -n prod
deployment.apps/nginx created

Comment: No, I do not reauthenticate.  I just use this:
az aks get-credentials --resource-group xxxx --name xxxxx --overwrite-existing. I can try reauthenticating. Its just me testing this out, so I switch my user between groups and test before assigning the group memberships for real users

Comment: Reauthentication did the trick :-) Thanks for the tip. The new roles reflect in the kubectl.

Comment: Updated my answer with fix ;)